# Use activity with include tag on android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I have a main layout and in this layout I use a button on android application, when user click on this button show a second layout(with include tag). How can I call activity(I mean activity for second layout)?
On second layout,I use a button, I want to set event for this button. How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to send parameters(values) to another activity?

Comment: Hey buddy,your query is not clear. As i thinks, you want to switch the activity from Ist to 2nd. and then wants the click event on button at 2nd activity. Is it?

Comment: As i have seen, you asked this question 2 times here. Why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381072/create-small-layout-on-the-main-layout-on-android

Comment: thanks guys.no,i don't want send parameters to another activity,i want call a second xml file into main xml file,i use of <includ> tag,but i can't use of second activity,@Vamshi,@Robi Kumar Tomar.  yes,i ask question before but any people don't answer but i deleted that post. please help me.thanks every one

Answer (score 1):

my main xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    layout="@layout/second"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

second.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#13352E" />



 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
  android:text="Close" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and this my mainactivity:

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout le=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
            le.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




        }
    });
}
```

and also this my secondactivity:

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout le=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        le.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }
});
```

on second activity,button on click not work

Answer (score 0):

you are making yourself confused.
you just need to add android:visibility="hidden" for the layout which you are treating as second xml.
then on Onclick of button change the visibility of this layout;